# I have a exception with java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, rest, dao

HEELP!!
I have a problem running the code, it does not execute the Sql statement and I cannot locate the error between the DAO class and the rest service.

I already added the exceptions of SQLException and ClassNotFound in the DAO class but I still cannot locate the error, and I already executed the code in a separate class and if the request of the BD returns, which means that the driver is well configured.

````
package com.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.connection.ConexionPSQL;
import com.IDAO.EmployeIDAO;
import com.model.EmployeObject;

public class EmployeDAO implements EmployeIDAO {

    @Override
    public List<EmployeObject> obtener() {

        Connection co = null;
        Statement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_EMPLOYES";

        List<EmployeObject> listaCliente = new 
                ArrayList<EmployeObject>();

        try {
            co = ConexionPSQL.crearConexion();
            stm = co.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {

                EmployeObject e = new EmployeObject();
                e.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                e.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
                e.setApellido(rs.getString(3));
                listaCliente.add(e);
            }
            stm.close();
            rs.close();
            co.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaCliente;

    }
}
`` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` `
package com.IDAO;

import java.util.List;

import com.model.EmployeObject;

public interface EmployeIDAO {

    public boolean registrar(EmployeObject employe);
    public List<EmployeObject> obtener();   
    public boolean actualizar(EmployeObject employe);
    public boolean eliminar(EmployeObject employe);
}

`` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` 
package REST;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.DAO.EmployeDAO;
import com.model.EmployeObject;


import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

// http://localhost:8080/RestService/resources/MyRestService/verEmpleados
     @GET
     @Path("/verEmpleados")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public List<EmployeObject> VerEmpleado() {


         List<EmployeObject> verEmpleados =  empleados.obtener();
         return verEmpleados;

   }


`` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` 


I hope I can help, thank you very much
Here are the error messages
````

10:55:27,125 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)

10:55:27,125 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)

10:55:27,125 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)

10:55:27,125 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)

10:55:27,126 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

10:55:27,126 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,126 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.connection.ConexionPSQL.crearConexion(ConexionPSQL.java:17)

10:55:27,126 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.DAO.EmployeDAO.obtener(EmployeDAO.java:55)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at REST.RestService.VerEmpleado(RestService.java:46)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,127 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)

10:55:27,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)

10:55:27,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)

10:55:27,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)

10:55:27,128 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)

10:55:27,129 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)

10:55:27,129 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)

10:55:27,129 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

10:55:27,129 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)

10:55:27,130 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

10:55:27,130 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

10:55:27,130 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

10:55:27,130 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

10:55:27,130 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

10:55:27,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

10:55:27,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

10:55:27,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

10:55:27,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

10:55:27,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

10:55:27,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

10:55:27,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

10:55:27,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,134 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

10:55:27,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

10:55:27,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:55:27,135 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

10:55:27,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

10:55:27,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

10:55:27,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

10:55:27,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

10:55:27,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

10:55:27,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

10:55:27,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)

10:55:27,137 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)

10:55:27,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)

10:55:27,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)

10:55:27,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

10:55:27,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

10:55:27,138 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

10:55:27,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)

10:55:27,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)

10:55:27,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

10:55:27,139 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Go about 5 lines down into your stack trace, your code starts to show up in it. The top of the trace is where the error lies, not the bottom. Show your ConexionPSQL class (double check there's no passwords) and on a personal note, don't use the `com` namespace as your top level project. Something like `com.nombre.project` is a bit more compatible with other projects, e.g. `com.olivas.psql...`